# CQL solr-query getting error - cannot pass json query

Tags: solr, cassandra, cql, datastax-enterprise, solr-query-syntax

I'm new to DSE. Working on DSE based queries to get date range

1) `select count(1) from tbl where solr_query='code:maf';`
It gives the result.

But When I'am trying to use range query is gives error :-

`select count(1) from tbl where solr_query='{q:dt:[ 2017-11-15T10:12:10 TO 2017-11-15T12:10:10Z] }';`

**Error :-** `Invalid Request: Error from Server: Code:2200 [Invalid Query] message="Cannot pass JSON query" '{q:dt:[ 2017-11-15T10:12:10 TO 2017-11-15T12:10:10Z] }'`

Where I'am going wrong? Please help

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need correctly format your query - it should be JSON inside, like this:

```
select count(1) from tbl where 
  solr_query='{"q":"dt:[ 2017-11-15T10:12:10 TO 2017-11-15T12:10:10Z]"}';
```

See [official documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.8/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchJSON.html) for detailed description.

Comment: Hi Alex, don't you think we should use Z for both side of ranges?

Comment: Is there any way to get the result in sorted order ?

Comment: Yes, you need to use Z on both sides - I simply copied your code... To sort in necessary order, add `, "sort":"dt asc"` before `}`